# Hadoop Cluster - Zero Memory

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I have two `VM` setup for the `Hadoop cluster`, as below.

```
VM-MASTER, 4GB Memory
VM-SLAVE, 4GB Memory
```

I have the following config for `yarn-site.xml`. When I goto http://VM-MASTEr:8088/cluster. I see `Memory Total` is 0, and `VCores Total` is 0. 
Am I missing something here?

I think this problem caused the job I submitted always in ACCEPTED state, and never move into RUNNING state. I'm using Hadoop 2.8.0.

```
<configuration>

<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>

 <value>500</value>
</property>


<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>

<value>2048</value>
</property>


<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>

<value>1</value>
</property>



</configuration>
```

Comment: Did you install all hadoop manually, or use something like Ambari?

Comment: I installed it manually on Ubuntu.

Comment: And did you use the official guide? Run the word count examples?

Comment: I followed the instruction at https://tecadmin.net/set-up-hadoop-multi-node-cluster-on-centos-redhat/.

Comment: I generally suggest following the official documentation as the first source, then if you are stuck, use a different tutorial, but always refer back. You probably missed some setting because that guide only says how to install and start, not actually *run anything*. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html